# SSRS Report Builder 3.0: Conditional Formatting Gradient Color

Tags: conditional-formatting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I can find plenty of tutorials on how to use conditional formatting of tablix fields in Report Builder 3.0. However I would like a function that creates a gradient color, from black to red, which colors the text more and more red, the closer it comes to a certain number.

For example I got a column with the age of a product component in days. I want the text to be black `(#000000)`, when the component is 0 days old. And then gradually turn into red, hitting a pure red `(#FF0000)` on the day it expires (could be day 30).

Can anyone provide me any information, regarding how to do that?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.sqljason.com/2013/02/custom-code-for-color-gradation-in-ssrs.html)?

Comment: I did actually find that excact article, after having posted here. I still havent been able to modify it to my purpose though. My main issue is that the example in the article goes from white to full color, rather than from black to full color. I am hoping to solve that issue today, and I will post the solution once it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up modifying the function from the solution linked by Alejandro.

```
Public Shared Function ColorDWB(ByVal Value As Decimal, ByVal MaxPositive As Decimal, ByVal Neutral As Decimal, ByVal ColStr As String) As String

'Initiate variables for Red, Green and Blue (RGB)
Dim ColVar1 As Integer
Dim ColVar2 As Integer
Dim ColVar3 As Integer

'Split the #RGB color to R, G, and B components
ColVar1=Convert.ToInt32(left(right(ColStr, 6),2),16)
ColVar2=Convert.ToInt32(left(right(ColStr, 4),2),16)
ColVar3=Convert.ToInt32(right(ColStr, 2),16)

'Find Largest Range
Dim decPosRange As Decimal = Math.Abs(MaxPositive - Neutral)

Dim iColor1 As Integer
Dim iColor2 As Integer
Dim iColor3 As Integer 
Dim strColor As String

'Reduce a shade for each of the R,G,B components
iColor1 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ColVar1, ColVar1*(Value-Neutral)/(MaxPositive-Neutral)))
iColor2 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ColVar2, ColVar2*(Value-Neutral)/(MaxPositive-Neutral)))
iColor3 = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ColVar3, ColVar3*(Value-Neutral)/(MaxPositive-Neutral)))

'Return the new color
strColor = "#" & iColor1.ToString("X2") & iColor2.ToString("X2") & iColor3.ToString("X2") 
Return strColor
End Function
```

Comment: Nice to see you made it suitable for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer before me, that article got me started but I modified to make it work better for my purposes.

```
Public Function HeatMap(ByVal Value As Double _
, ByVal MinVal As Double _
, ByVal MaxVal As Double _
, ByVal RValLo As Double _
, ByVal GValLo As Double _
, ByVal BValLo As Double _
, ByVal RValHi As Double _
, ByVal GValHi As Double _
, ByVal BValHi As Double _
) As String
Dim DiffPercent As Double
Dim RNew As Integer
Dim GNew As Integer
Dim BNew As Integer

Dim HeatMapColor As String
If Value = Nothing Then
    RNew = 255
    GNew = 255
    BNew = 255
ElseIf Value <= MinVal Then
    RNew = RValLo
    GNew = GValLo
    BNew = BValLo
ElseIf Value >= MaxVal Then
    RNew = RValHi
    GNew = GValHi
    BNew = BValHi
Else
    DiffPercent = (Value - MinVal) / (MaxVal - MinVal)
    RNew = RValLo - Round((RValLo - RValHi) * DiffPercent, 0)
    GNew = GValLo - Round((GValLo - GValHi) * DiffPercent, 0)
    BNew = BValLo - Round((BValLo - BValHi) * DiffPercent, 0)
End If

HeatMapColor = "#" & Hex(RNew) & Hex(GNew) & Hex(BNew)

   HeatMap = HeatMapColor
End Function
```

More info on my approach here: [How to create heat map on a table in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999534/how-to-create-heat-map-on-a-table-in-ssrs/71831623#71831623)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).